# simple cms - only to create/edit content and export it via jdbc or java api

Tags: java, content-management-system

(i even don't know if i need a cms)
 what i need is: a simple web based way for a functional department to create/edit multilingual text documents (probably tagged with customizable semantic tags).
The containing Texts are used in an RIA showing statistical data and infos about it. This infos and other user visible Stings should be fully managed by functional department.

the destination of the this texts/documents is an embedded apache derby db - delivered together with RIA release (as zip-File,- the texts are static).

So on the other hand the cms (if this is an cms) should provide an interface to export the data - either a simple db-structure to get data via jdbc or a java api.

so what cmc/?? do you suggest for this usecase

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a java web framework like [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) to create a simple web application.
It has some premade components too easily modify and save data to a database.

Comment: i don't want to create another app. i need something with a minimum of  effort on java/ria-dev side. i want somthing that i could download and deliver to functional department. the only effort i want have is configuration and development of the interface cms->apache derby.